# Magento asks for IMG url, but this field is emty

Tags: magento2

Get this error when I try to import a CSV to Magento ver. 2.3.4:
Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from an external resource due to timeout or access permissions.

I don't have any image links in my CSV, and I don't wanna do that.

Can someone tell me what to do, or what I do wrong?

Some of the products get uploaded, but most of them don't.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed this dropdown, and now it does the job.[image]